# Using recursion to find the minimum character in a given string

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a method that returns the minimum character (using ASCII sequence) in a given string. Example minChar("hello"); should return 'e'.

Currently I am trying to run minChar("hello", 0). My thinking is that it will start at h (h < ~) so it would set c = h, then call minChar("hello", 1), assign c = e, and so on comparing the letters before finally returning 'e' since that is minimum value. What am I missing?

```
public static char minChar(String x, int z){
    char c = '~';
    while(z < x.length()){
        if(x.charAt(z) < c){
            c = x.charAt(z);
        }
        minChar(x, z+1);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using what is returned from `minChar()`. Use it.

```
public static char minChar(String x, int z){
    char c = '~';
    if(z < x.length()){
        if(x.charAt(z) < c){
            c = x.charAt(z);
        }
        char candidate = minChar(x, z+1); // add assignment
        if (candidate < c) c = candidate; // add update
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please change `while` to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, it works for me:

```
public  String minChar(String x, int z){
   if(z==0)
   {
       c=x.substring(0);
   }
    while(z < x.length()){
        if(x.substring(z,z+1).compareTo(c)<0){
            c = x.substring(z,z+1);
        }
        z++;
        minChar(x, z);
    }
    return c;
}
```